# Upload video to specific playlist

Tags: php, youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am uploading video to my channel with youtube data  api. This works perfectly but when i upload video it uploads in my channel. I want it to upload in given playlist.(I have some already created playlists). Is there any way i can give playlistId in following code. I dont want to use playlistitem.insert.
 thanks in Advance

```
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'ds';
    $OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'sd';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
// Define an object that will be used to make all API requests.
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$tokenExisted = $this->Token->find('first');

 if(!empty($tokenExisted)){

$token = $tokenExisted['Token']['token'];
$refreshToken = $tokenExisted['Token']['ref_token'];
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();

}





if (isset($token)) {

  $client->setAccessToken($token);

}

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){    

$refreshToken = $tokenExisted['Token']['ref_token'];
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$token = $client->getAccessToken();

}else{

 $token = $client->getAccessToken();
}
$token=json_encode($token);

// Check to ensure that the access token was successfully acquired.
 if ($token) {
 try{
// REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
$videoPath = $dest . '/' . $img_name . '.' . $image['1'];


// Create a snippet with title, description, tags and category ID
// Create an asset resource and set its snippet metadata and type.
// This example sets the video's title, description, keyword tags, and
// video category.
$snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$snippet->setTitle($input['title']);
$snippet->setDescription($input['description']);
//$snippet->playlistId($playlistId);

// Numeric video category. See
// https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
$snippet->setCategoryId($input['category']);

// Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
// "private" and "unlisted".
$status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$status->privacyStatus = "public";

// Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
$video->setSnippet($snippet);
$video->setStatus($status);

// Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
// reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
// value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

// Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
// with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
$client->setDefer(false);

// Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
$insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

// Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $insertRequest,
    'video/*',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


// Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {

  $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
  $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);

}
fclose($handle);

// If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
//$client->setDefer(false);



} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
$htmlBody = sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
$htmlBody = sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}


  } else {
 // If the user hasn't authorized the app, initiate the OAuth flow

 $state = mt_rand();
 $client->setState($state);
 $_SESSION['state'] = $state;

 $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35672247/5832311), you cannot upload video directly into a playlist. It's normal that when uploading video, it will redirect to your channel. Once it's uploaded in the channel, you can now put it in the playlist.

If the video is already uploaded, you can follow this [Adding a video to a playlist](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Adding_a_Playlist_Video) documentation. You can add a video to a playlist by using a `VideoEntry` object.

Here's a sample code retrieves a `VideoEntry` object with a known entry ID and then adds it to the playlist corresponding to the `PlaylistListEntry` object. Since the request does not specify a position where the video will appear in the playlist, the new video is added to the end of the playlist.

```
$postUrl = $playlistToAddTo->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl();
// video entry to be added
$videoEntryToAdd = $yt->getVideoEntry('4XpnKHJAok8');

// create a new Zend_Gdata_PlaylistListEntry, passing in the underling DOMElement of the VideoEntry
$newPlaylistListEntry = $yt->newPlaylistListEntry($videoEntryToAdd->getDOM());

// post
try {
  $yt->insertEntry($newPlaylistListEntry, $postUrl);
} catch (Zend_App_Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here's a related SO post which might help:

- [Youtube API (PHP) - how to add (existing) video to existing playlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692416/youtube-api-php-how-to-add-existing-video-to-existing-playlist)